# Media query for targeting iPad

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, media-queries

I have an issue with writing specific queries for iPad Pro and iPad which appear on google Chrome developer tools... 
I cant target iPad Pro e.g.

"and (min-device-width: 768px) 
 and (max-device-width: 1024px)"

But it also happens to work for other resolutions like

"and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
 and (max-device-width: 1366px)"

Does anybody have answer as to how I write different media query rules for different iPad sizes?
Thanks a lot : )

Comment: did you check the order of your media queries?

Answer (score 1):

iPads can use the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` query to check if the screen is retina or not. Older iPads have a `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` value of `1`. iPad 3 and above have a value of `2`, while both having the same screen dimensions.

```css
/* iPad 1, 2, Mini and Air */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad 3, 4 and Pro 9.7" */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

CSSTricks have [a great post on this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to recognize all kinds of devices.